# How to fix this issue: The rule set cannot be converted into an equivalent IIS format because control flow flags (C, S, N) are not supported

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I am moving a website from a Linux server to Windows 2016 and need to import the .htaccess rewrite rules. I get the above error on these rules:

```
# if this request is for "/" or has already been rewritten
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php)?$ [OR]
# or if request is for image, css, or js file
RewriteCond $1 \.(css|js)$ [NC,OR]
# or if root images folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images(.*) [NC,OR]
# or if URL resolves to existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# or if URL resolves to existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# then skip the rewrite to WP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [S=1,L]

RewriteCond $2 \.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)/images/([^/]+) /images/$2 [S=1,L]

# else rewrite the request
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have very little experience with Linux and hope someone can help out with a solution to this.

Comment: Flags are separated by a comma in Apache. `NC` is one flag, not two, standing for No Case and means the regex should match in a case insensitive manner. The `S=1` flag means to Skip the next rule or condition afterwards if the rewrite rule matches anything. It's actually very powerful in terms of providing an if/else sort of logic to Apache's rewriting logic. The dash at the end of the rule has special meaning and means to leave the request unchanged. This is all tied to the rewrite condition in order to skip the image rewrite section if the initial rewrite conditions are true.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any suggestions what would be the equivalent on Windows Server (IIS 10)?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--# then skip the rewrite to WP-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <!--# if this request is for "/" or has already been rewritten-->
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php)?$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <!--# or if request is for image, css, or js file-->
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="\.(css|js)$" />
        <!--# or if root images folder-->
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/images(.*)" />
        <!--# or if URL resolves to existing file-->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
        <!--# or if URL resolves to existing directory-->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.+)/images/([^/]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{R:2}" pattern="\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/images/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <!--# else rewrite the request-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```